# dependencies - gradle - drools (Version 4.0.7)

Tags: java, gradle, drools

I have the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile (
                [group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-core', version: '4.0.7'],   
                [group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-compiler', version: '4.0.7'],
                [group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-jsr94', version: '4.0.7']
        )
```

}

And i get the following exception:

```
Could not resolve org.mvel:mvel:1.3.1-java1.4.
Required by:
  project : > org.drools:drools-core:4.0.7
  > Could not resolve org.mvel:mvel:1.3.1-java1.4.
  > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: 
      org.codehaus.mvel:mvel:1.3.1-java1.4 Errors: bad group: 
      expected='org.mvel' found='org.codehaus.mvel'
```

If i update my dependencies to drools 5.0.1 then it works. But i need drools 4.0.7.

What can i do? (Exclude org.mvel from the transitive dependencies of drools doesn't solve the problem.....)

Comment: Which repository have you defined?

Comment: our company nexus

Comment: Well then this dependency is not available there

Comment: our nexus is connected to maven central

Comment: this dependency is available the problem is the bad group (org.mvel vs. org.codehaus.mvel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the root issue is that the artifact up on maven central is bad: see [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C3%7Cg%3A%22org.mvel%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mvel%22) leading to [this pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mvel/mvel/1.3.1-java1.4/mvel-1.3.1-java1.4.pom).

also looks like there's no way to skip this validation in gradle - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586289/how-to-ignore-bad-pom-inconsistent-module-descriptor-version).

since you said your running your own repository i'd say your best bet is to upload a fixed artifact (fixed pom) into your own repository such that it would be pulled instead of the artifact from maven central - worst case exclude `org.mvel:mvel:1.3.1-java1.4` and put an explicit dependency on the artifact which you would put up on your own repo under something like `org.mvel.relocated:mvel:1.3.1-java1.4` (you would need the modified pom to match)